# groovy - Sql eachRow named parameters with map

Tags: sql, select, groovy, named-parameters

I'm trying to perform select like this:

```
def queries = [
    [
        paramQuey: "",
        mainQuery: "SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE"
    ],
    [
        paramQuey: "SELECT SOME_COLUMN AS COUNT FROM A_TABLE WHERE SOMETHING=3",
        mainQuery: "SELECT * FROM OTHER_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM<:COUNT"
    ]
]

queries.each {
    def params = [:]
    if(!it.paramQuery.isEmpty()) {
        params = sql.firstRow(it.paramQuery)
    }
    sql.eachRow(mainQuery, params) { //<--here's my problem
        //do something
    }
}
```

However, program throws

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.sql.Sql.eachRow() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedHashMap, MyClass$_execute_closure4) values: [SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE, [:], MyClass$_execute_closure4@b3600d]
Possible solutions: eachRow(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure), eachRow(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure, groovy.lang.Closure), eachRow(java.lang.String, java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure), eachRow(groovy.lang.GString, groovy.lang.Closure), eachRow(groovy.lang.GString, groovy.lang.Closure, groovy.lang.Closure), eachRow(java.lang.String, int, int, groovy.lang.Closure)
```

which clearly shows that there's no method for handling eachRow with named parameters. However according to http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html there are:

```
    void    eachRow(java.lang.String sql, java.util.Map params, Closure closure)
    void    eachRow(java.lang.String sql, java.util.Map params, Closure metaClosure, Closure rowClosure)
    void    eachRow(java.lang.String sql, java.util.Map map, Closure metaClosure, int offset, int maxRows, Closure rowClosure)
    void    eachRow(java.lang.String sql, java.util.Map params, int offset, int maxRows, Closure closure)
    void    eachRow(java.util.Map params, java.lang.String sql, Closure closure)
    void    eachRow(java.util.Map params, java.lang.String sql, Closure metaClosure, Closure rowClosure)
    void    eachRow(java.util.Map map, java.lang.String sql, Closure metaClosure, int offset, int maxRows, Closure rowClosure)
    void    eachRow(java.util.Map params, java.lang.String sql, int offset, int maxRows, Closure closure)
```

which leaves me wondering: what am I doing wrong, and how can I handle named parameters with eachRow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `eachRow` method you are referring to is available since Groovy 1.8.7:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#eachRow(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map,%20groovy.lang.Closure)

I assume you are using a Groovy version prior to 1.8.7.

Comment: unfortunately, no: Groovy Version: 2.0.5 JVM: 1.6.0_35 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Windows XP

Comment: is there any chance that there is another Groovy version in your projects classpath?

Comment: Well, that may be the case, since I'm using Gradle and it seems that it is providing it's own groovy